# Can you pick up animals in adventure mode in Minecraft Earth?

Tags: minecraft-earth

In Minecraft Earth, there are places you can go that are indicated by beams of light. When you reach one of these, you can go into adventure mode, where you can see animals, mine, and gather materials.

When you're on your build plot, you can just pick up animals and add them to your inventory. Does this functionality exist in adventure mode or are the animals purely there to be killed?

Comment: I was about to suggest asking on Meta, but then I remembered that I can create the tag myself. :D

Comment: @FabianRöling haha, thanks for the edit then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, the game includes several modes and these change what you do with mobs:

- **Map Mode** - you can gather mobs into your inventory, just like other resources
- **Build Mode** - mobs can be placed on your build plate from your inventory or they can be picked up and returned to your inventory
- **Adventure Mode** - mobs are there as a challenge. You interact with mobs by fighting them. There is (as far as I know) no provision for picking up mobs & adding them to your inventory like the other modes.

Note that this is just what I have observed in my 2-3 days of playing. I don't claim to be an expert (yet).